# Terminal SED regex fails with dash and slash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal

I try to convert filenames and remove special chars and whitespaces.
For some reasons my SED regex don't work if I declare dash and slashes not to be replaced.

Input: `/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg` expected output: `/path/to/file_20-456_1.jpg`

Example:

`echo "/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg" | sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\_\-\/]//g'`

Output:

`/path/to/file_20456_1.jpg`

So the dash isn't in.
When I try this command:

`echo "/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg" | sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\_\-]//g'`

Output:

`pathtofile_20-456_1.jpg`

the dash is there but without the directory slashes I can't move the files.
I wonder why the replacment with dash didn't work anymore if I add `\/` into regex pattern.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The hyphen must be put at the end of the bracket expression. Does `sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's,[^0-9a-zA-Z._/-],,g'` work as expected? Do you want to get `/path/to/file_20-456_1.jpg`?

Comment: Pehaps you should specify which output you would like to achieve. When you just say `remove special chars`, I don't know which characters are "special" for you.

Comment: ah yes my expected path is `/path/to/file_20-456_1.jpg` and thx Wiktor, your solution worked. Strange before when I don't escaped the dash is get errors.

Comment: @Dominic, kindly don't enter your solution in your question, you could use answer section in case you want to post an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```
echo "/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg" | 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {gsub(/ /,"_",$NF);gsub(/-|\(|\)/,"",$NF)} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, by `echo` printing value `/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg` as a standard input to `awk` program. In `awk` program, setting `FS` and `OFS` to `/` in `BEGIN` section. Then in main program using `gsub` to globally substitute space with `_` in last field($NF) and then globally substitute `-` OR `(` OR `)` with NULL in last field and then mentioning `1` will print that line.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the result using [string manipulation in Bash](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
path="/path/to/file 20-456 (1).jpg"
fldr="${path%/*}"   # Get the folder
file="${path##*/}"  # Get the file name
file="${file// /_}" # Replace spaces with underscores in filename
echo "$fldr/${file//[^[:alnum:]._-]/}" # Get the result
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nYYsHa) yielding `/path/to/file_20-456_1.jpg`.

Quick notes:

- `${path%/*}` - Removes the smallest chunk up to `/` from the end of the `path`
- `${path##*/}` - Removes the largest text chunk from start of `path` to last `/` (including it)
- `${file// /_}` replaces all spaces with `_` in `file`
- `${file//[^[:alnum:]._-]/}` removes all chars that are not alphanumeric, `.`, `_` and `-` from `file`.